# Calculations with vectors and matrices

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, symbolic, vector

[image]

Given the following equation. How can I run this in mathematica and get the same result?

I naively tried it like this, with:

```
A = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}
b = {0, 1}
x = {x1, x2}
p = {p1, p2}
u = u
```

and

```
  1 + p.(A.x + b.u)
```

which results in

```
1 + p2 {0, 1}.u + p1 (x2 + {0, 1}.u)
```

or

```
1 + p.(A*x + b*u)
```

which results in

```
{1 + p2 u, 1 + p2 u + p1 x1}
```

which is also wrong. In short, I don't get it somehow, can anybody help me out here?

Comment: Vector x should be transposed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
1+p.(A.x + b*u)
```

Use `.` for matrix multiplication or vector dot products. Use `*` for element-wise scalar product. Since `u` is a scalar, use `*` to multiply it with the vector `b`.

Comment: works, thank you! :)